# Groovy/Grails plugin for Sonar

Tags: grails, groovy, plugins, static-analysis, sonarqube

Sonar is an application for integrating output from several static and test analysis tools into a comprehensive overview of the software's quality.

Unfortunately, most of those analysis tools (PDM, FindBugs, etc.) do not support Groovy and, by extension, Grails.

We've found tools called CodeNarc and GMetrics which perform some of the analysis, but not test coverage, and we're working on a Sonar plugin to import the CodeNarc output.  As I said, though, this is incomplete.

Does anyone know of a better set of complexity/rules-based static analysis tools that can handle Groovy, as well as a Grails test coverage metric?  Of course, one with a Sonar plugin for reading in the output would be best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the tools I'm aware of (and just aware):

- There is CodeNarc that you mentioned.
- There is also [GMetrics](http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/).
- And Grails has a [Test Code Coverage Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/code-coverage).

But nothing ready to be used with Sonar AFAIK. I'm watching [SONARPLUGINS-194](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-194) about this but there isn't much activity although some work has been reported very recently, maybe be you :)

Answer (score 15):

Just use [Sonar Groovy Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Groovy+Plugin)!

It leverages GMetrics, Codenarc and Cobertura in Sonar!

Comment: Sonar Groovy plugin makes use of CodeNarc, GMetrics, Cobertura

Comment: Also this blog can help you configure sonarqube with grails http://hussain.io/2014/12/setting-up-sonarqube-for-grails-project/